# What is the length of a projected side of a right triangle onto another line that intersects the triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, projection

Given any [right triangle $FGH$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajuEh.png) with right angle at vertex $G$.  A line $L$ intersects $G$ at some angle $\theta$ relative to short side GF (assume acute angle). Extend $HF$ so it intersects line $L$ at $K$.  What is the length of $GK$ in terms of length $GF$ (that is, $GK$ projected onto line $L$ as viewed from vertex $H$)?

At first I thought dividing $GF$ by $\cos(\theta)$ or $\tan(\theta)$ would work, but no.  This is not the usual projection, that is, using a perpendicular to $L$ from $F$.  After much thought but no idea what to do, I'm stumped.

I'm trying to derive the sum of $\arctan(x) + \arctan(y)$ identity (I have not included the drawing that would pertain directly to that), but I need to solve this part of the problem first.

Comment: Add your attempt to your question Thank you.

Comment: Suggest you add a drawing.

Comment: Your writing is not reflected in the drawing

Comment: 1. Post a proper sketch of the question. 2. What you've wrote in the answer is not your attempt but query. 3. Add more context: given data or we've to find answer in terms of what?